# Is poetry written along the known song legal from the view point of copyright?

Tags: copyright, poetry, music

I wrote some (humorous) poetry that uses a known song as a pattern. The poetry could be sung instead of the original words of the song but I do not have any musical background to perform such a singing. All I think, the poetry  could be interesting for some writing communities. Am I allowed to share in public the text of my poetry that is completely different from the original text of the song?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean you wrote new lyrics to the music of an existing song? That is perfectly legal and you can publish those lyrics (as long as they are completely unrelated to the original lyrics) and even state which song you wrote them for, but if you want to use the music of the song you have to pay performance royalties.

Comment: Don't forget the power of parody. In most places, if your song is a parody, it is perfectly legal.

Comment: @ShadowOfHassen even being perfectly legal, it doesn't shield from legal harassment. But it is such a popular subject that a web search can tell where it stands in a certain jurisdiction. As usual, the StackExchange and its users offer no legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a lawyer, but as my dad used to say: "As long as you're not trying to make money off it, you can pretty much do any damn thing you want."

And especially if it's humorous and you claim it's a parody. Google "Alfred Yankovic" for examples.

And you've already discovered the best security method: Classifying anything as a "poem" offers a hundred times the protection of even the best NSA-rated encryption algorithm.